# Virtualbox: Intel adapter types are unsupported

Tags: virtualbox

I had this error trying to launch virtualbox using adapters of intel type

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine BackTrack.

Configuration error: Failed to get the "MAC"; value (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

No boot problems with other adapters (PCNet), but then networking doesn't work. I'm using the last version of vbox on a macosx 6. The guest is a linux.

Answer (score 3):

Try this - using a console and below command find what additonal data you have set:

> VBoxManage getextradata "The Name Of Your Virtual Machine" enumerate

Typically it starts with "Key: VBoxInternal/"...

Remove these custom settings using:

> VBoxManage setextradata "The Name Of Your Virtual Machine" "VBoxInternal/Whatever/Custom/Setting/You/Did/Yourself"

For example my problem was resolved with:

> VBoxManage setextradata "The Name Of Your Virtual Machine" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/DNSProxy"

Thanks goes to this post http://myblogisinbeta.blogspot.com/2011/10/virtualbox-un-fuck-installation.html